# Trying to move a range on an excel spreadsheet to another spreadsheet based on a value in a column

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have this code that works pretty good, I would like to make a few changes to it and I don't know exactly how to do it.

```
Sub movetosheet2()

    Dim xRg As Range
    Dim xCell As Range
    Dim I As Long
    Dim J As Long
    Dim K As Long
    I = Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Rows.Count
    J = Worksheets("Sheet2").UsedRange.Rows.Count
    If J = 1 Then
       If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets("Sheet2").UsedRange) = 0 Then J = 0
    End If
    Set xRg = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C1:C" & I)
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For K = 1 To xRg.Count
        If CStr(xRg(K).Value) = "Done" Then
            xRg(K).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & J + 1)
            xRg(K).EntireRow.Delete
            If CStr(xRg(K).Value) = "Done" Then
                K = K - 1
            End If
            J = J + 1
        End If
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

I'd like to only copy a range instead of an entire row. So if this code copies row 8 from sheet 1 to sheet 2, I would like it to copy `C8:J8` instead.  Also instead of deleting row 8 in sheet 1, I would prefer if I could get it to Clear the content of `C8:J8` in sheet 1.

Answer (score 2):

> If this code copies row 8 from sheet 1 to sheet 2, I would like it to copy `C8:J8` instead.

```
Dim rng As Range, r As Long
r = 8 ' Your Row #
Set Rng = Range("C" & r & ":J" & r)
```

---

> Also instead of deleting row 8 in sheet 1, I would prefer if I could get it to Clear the content of C8:J8 in sheet 1.

Take the same `rng` object from above:

```
rng.ClearContents
```